# Error Response not parsed by Faraday despite adding :json middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, faraday

I initialize my Faraday client this way:

```rb
@client = Faraday.new(url: BASE_URL) do |faraday|
  faraday.request  :json
  faraday.response :json

  faraday.response :raise_error
end
```

And when I rescue the `Faraday::ClientError`, the response's body looks like this:

```rb
irb> e.response[:body]
"{\"error\":\"access_denied\",\"error_description\":\"Unauthorized\"}"
```

I would expect it to be parsed and have the body be a Hash. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Faraday, [the order of registration of middlewares matters](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/pull/1135#pullrequestreview-383392633) because it's a pipeline (similar to Rack).

So if you put the `:raise_error` middleware before `:json`, the error's body will be parsed.

```rb
@client = Faraday.new(url: BASE_URL) do |faraday|
  faraday.request  :json

  faraday.response :raise_error
  faraday.response :json
end
```